# USB HUB module for Rasberry Pi A+

Tags: usb, hub

Does anyone have experience with USB hub module. I tried to use GL850G but I could not connect to the modem via the USB port
[GL850G](http://www.gotronik.pl/portowy-hub-usb-20-pasywny-p-2782.html)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, but I would be slightly way of its use.  I have used other unpowered hubs with the RPi before, and it was my experience that the combination of powering the hub itself and the things connected to it often caused power issues.

I would highly recommend sticking to a powered hub, especially when you have something power hungry like a wireless radio combined with anything else.